# Does anyone know where to buy chance island or chance planet?

Tags: identify-this-game

These were two cassette story games for kids made my Phillips and Lacey but they have stopped production now and I came up short on Amazon.

These were a staple to my childhood and the reason I play so many games today and I wish to let my children experience them the same as me. They were both around 1990s and were played on Cassettes with a pencil and paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question, which will quickly become out of date.

Comment: @Thunderforge okay fair enough, in all honesty I had no idea where to ask this, is there anywhere else you know of to ask?

Comment: I don't think there are any Stack Exchange sites that would be appropriate. Try BoardGameGeek.com, which has sections for buying and selling, or Reddit.

Comment: Alright, cheers! Sorry for the off post

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes. Hopefully there are other questions that this site can answer!